# Getting "Open with" on top of the Context Menu in Win10 w/o additional software?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

As I work on different computers with different programs installed, I often have to search for the `Open with`-dialog in the Context Menu, as the Context Menu is seemingly sorted alphabetically, and therefore, lots of programs might - and will - stand in front or after it.

So I want to move `Open with` to the top of the list, as shown here:

[image: diagram of context menu]

As I don't really like third-party programs that mess around with my Registry and come with all sorts of OpenCandy and the likes, I want to do this the old-fashioned, manual way - and I immediately hit a problem.

A bit of googling around led me to [this SO-question called "Order in the Windows Explorer context menu"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007852/order-in-the-windows-explorer-context-menu) that in turn led me to [this - rather old - blogpost from MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freeassociations/2005/05/19/how-do-explorer-context-menus-sort-verbs/) stating that:

> [...] the sorting is based on the following elements in decision order:
>
> 1. Key priority (eg, txtfile, *, AFSO)
> 2. Registry Enumeration order of `shellex\contextmenuhandlers` with a special case for static verbs always being first
> 3. `IContextMenu` Implementation order

---

The only solution I can think of is very unelegant: Renaming `Open with` into something like `1: Open with` or `0pen with`. I tried that, but unfortunately, this removes `Open with` completely (as in: it is no longer in the context menu).

Another solution I read of in the SO-question was to place `Open with` inside another section of the Context Menu. I would like to avoid this, too, as it would only help slightly , because the amount of programs would still influence the position.

---

Is there any way to get `Open with` on top via the manual way, e.g. via Regedit or PowerShell?

**Note:** To me, it does not really matter if it comes before or after `Open`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of changing position of regular `Open with` from `HKCR\*\shellex\contextmenuhandlers` in the context menu popup, you can **add** next other `Open with` under `HKCR\*\shell` and *force its position to the top* in the popup as follows:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\.OpenWith]
"Position"="Top"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\.OpenWith\command]
@="{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}"
```

**Result** (an example with a `.png` file):

[image: OpenWith]

**To revert changes back**, read and follow [Deleting Registry Keys and Values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg)

> To delete a registry key with a `.reg` file, put a hyphen (`-`) in
>   front of the *RegistryPath* in the `.reg` file.

In this case, to delete the `.OpenWith` subkey from the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell` registry key, use:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\.OpenWith]
```